# Does Python add exception list appends to the end of try/except?

Tags: python, exception

I am making a POST request to a website which contains the store name, street and city for a number of stores, each in their own card on the webpage. I'm trying to record that data from the site using xpath. There are a small number of items (e.g. a store name) that cannot be read, generating an IndexError, and I am trying to handle those errors with a try-except.

In the below code, there is only an error when reading a single title variable, and appending that to a name list. My code catches the exception, but for some reason this 'X_NAME_ERROR_X' element is appended to the end of the list - e.g. ['place1', 'place 2', 'place 4', 'X_NAME_ERROR_X'], when I know that the exception is occurring in what would be 'place3'.

Is there a reason why python would append the excepted code variable at the end of the list, even thought the exception should have been raised before the end of the for loop?

```
rest_count = len(response.html.xpath('//*[@id="search-results-container"]//div[@class="mb-32 width--full"]'))

names = []
street_address = []
city_address = []
for item in range(rest_count):
    try:
        title = response.html.xpath('//*[@id="search-results-container"]//div[@class="mb-32 width--full"]/h4/text()')[item]
        names.append(title)
    except IndexError:
        title = 'X_NAME_ERROR_X'
        names.append(title)
    try:
        street = response.html.xpath('//*[@id="search-results-container"]//div[@class="mb-32 width--full"]/p[1]/text()')[item]
        street_address.append(street)
    except IndexError:
        street = 'X_STREET_ERROR_X'
        street_address.append(street)
    try:
        city = response.html.xpath('//*[@id="search-results-container"]//div[@class="mb-32 width--full"]/p[2]/text()')[item]
        city_address.append(city)
    except IndexError:
        city = 'X_CITY_ERROR_X'
        city_address.append(city)
```

Comment: "when I know that the exception is occurring in what would be 'place3'" - sounds like you're wrong about that.

Comment: Actually, there's no way you could get an IndexError *between* two valid indices.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica So it's always just going to give that error at the end because the index is non-existent? Even though the length of the rest_count object is the full number of stores that show any data on the webpage?

Comment: The xpath selector you used to compute `rest_count` selects more things than the one you used for `title`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I see. Because of the additional "/h4"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure you're trying to index goes `[thing1, thing2, thing4]`, not `[thing1, thing2, some_magic_thing_that_raises_an_IndexError, thing4]`. Indices 0, 1, and 2 are valid, but index 3 is out of range, so you get an IndexError at the end. You may have expected to have an extra thing between things 2 and 4, but that's not where the IndexError happens.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how this works. I will have to go back to try accessing the element that can't be read using a different approach, and hopefully that generates an error I can then handle in another way.